# Is there any possibility to get explain plan results from stored procedures?

Tags: sql-execution-plan, explain, singlestore

Explain plan, show plan and other commands are not allowed in stored procedures.
I thought, I will call back from plancache (as per documentation said [here](https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/tools/memsql-ops/managing-plancache/)), but there are no plans in there.

I am on cluster-in-a-box, with memsql 7.0.15.

Regards,
  cashy

Comment: Any answers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from version memsql 7.1 EXPLAIN, PROFILE, and SHOW PROFILE are now allowed inside of stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can show explains in the plancache with the command `SHOW PLAN <plan_id>`, after you have enabled enable_disk_plan_explain. See https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/reference/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language-dml/explain/

Comment: I could not execute show plan <plan_id> from a stored procedure. I need this in runtime. I want to store plans for further analysis.